# Lawnmowers , just why?

Tags: oil, small-engine, lawnmower

I was mowing the lawns the other day , I managed to knock the oil cap loose and oil spurted out into the engine block I didn't think it was that much oil so I put the lid back on and kept mowing , the next day I had to mow the back lawns so I started the mower , it stayed on for about two minutes then died out after refilling the oil then tinkering I've noticed oil on the spark plug and in the well I'm currently in the process of trying to dry the well...thoughts? The mower is a six-month-old Victa , classic cut , 4 stroke

Comment: You might be better off asking this on Motor Vehicles.SE.  They have a lot of lawnmower questions.  It is more of a mechanical question than plant.

Comment: You can have a fun time rebuilding the motor, and perhaps learn not to ignore oil loss.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic - ie not about gardening or landscaping

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that this has anything to do with gardening or landscaping - it is about a motor.   If you don't want to deal with combusion engines, get a battery powered one.  If you want to complain about product design/limitations, there are review sites for that.